# The atribute fill of my svg is none and I want to change it

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg, icons

I have a svg icon and the fill:none is predefined. I want to put a rgb color on it but it doesnt work!

```
.complete-look svg {
    padding: 2px;
    fill: black; (doenst work)
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
svg[Estilo de atributos] {
    width: 32;
    height: 32;
    fill: none;
```

Comment: how are you including the icon. Please add a [mcve] rather than just a bit of CSS. Use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you can.

Comment: Also we need to know how the original icon fill is being set.  Is it a `fill="xxx"` attribute or a `style="fill:xxx"` attribute?

Answer (score -1):

The css cannot overwrite the color as your svg load.
You can change the color in the  tag of your svg icon
i.e. `<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="rgb(255,0,0)" d="M532.4 ..."/>`, can change the `fill=""` in `fill="#000"` in your case.